# Trying to grab ID's from CSV file and iterate through them with my program. Unsure where to start

Tags: python, csv, web

I am writing a program to automate my data entry job. I need it to be able to run through a specific ID number then onto the next one, I am unsure where to start with grabbing the CSV data which is just column of ~1500 or so IDs.
Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver


import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
web = webdriver.Chrome()





#navigates to login page
web.get('https://id.pcgeducation.com/id093')
time.sleep(1)
web.maximize_window()
#finds elements and fills form
user =  web.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"form-control")
user.send_keys("aaa@aaa.com")

password =  web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/input")
password.send_keys("aaa!aaa")

web.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'btn').click()
time.sleep(2)
web.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li[1]/a').click()
time.sleep(2)
student = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/fieldset/div[1]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[7]/div/input")
```

####NEED TO CHANGE THIS ID AS IT ITERATES THROUGH LIST

```
student.send_keys("0000000000")
web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/fieldset/div[1]/div[1]/div/form    /div/div[3]/button").click()

time.sleep(2)
```

####NEED TO CHANGE THIS ID AS IT ITERATES THROUGH LIST

```
web.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA").click()
time.sleep(2)
class CheckBoxes():
    def CheckBoxes(self):
                    web.find_element(By.ID,"checkbox_d5rw7nmmu9s_1").click()
web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[3]/div/ul/li[6]/a").click()
time.sleep(2)
web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/fieldset/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[9]/a/div[2]").click()
time.sleep(2)

rev1 = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/fieldset/div[1]/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/textarea")
rev1.clear()
time.sleep(1)
rev1.send_keys("This Transfer Decision was created for the purpose of migrating the student's current IEP and Eligibility data from the district's prior special education platform to a new platform (EDPlan). The student's IEP and Eligibility report has not been altered.")

rev2 = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/fieldset/div[1]/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/textarea")
rev2.clear()
time.sleep(1)
rev2.send_keys("This Transfer Decision was created for the purpose of migrating the student's current IEP and Eligibility data from the district's prior special education platform to a new platform (EDPlan). The student's IEP and Eligibility report has not been altered.")


rev3 = web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/fieldset/div[1]/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/textarea")
rev3.clear()
time.sleep(1)
rev3.send_keys("This Transfer Decision was created for the purpose of migrating the student's current IEP and Eligibility data from the district's prior special education platform to a new platform (EDPlan). The student's IEP and Eligibility report has not been altered.")


web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/fieldset/div[1]/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/label").click()
web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/fieldset/div[1]/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/label").click()


web.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/fieldset/div[1]/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div[3]/button").click()
```

I flagged the ID's that I need to change as it goes through said list. I am not asking for someone to write my code lol but I need direction is how to pull this data through a CSV then loop through it till finish.

Comment: start with standard module [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) (and examples at the end of this page) or install module `pandas` which also can read file `csv`. You can even find many examples in other questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: and later you need `for`-loop to run the same code with different IDs. And `f-string` (or `.format()`) to create string with different IDs.